# iphone mkannotationview strange problem - possibly being reused

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I've just found a strange issue with my sub classed mkannotationview.

When I add the first 5 markers, they all work perfectly. In the mkannotationview sub class, I NSLog a message which I see 5 times. However, when I remove ALL the markers and redraw them - using all the same methods, I see the NSLog only once.

It's like the map is reusing existing annotationviews? Is there a way to force it to use new ones each time?

[UPDATE with code]

So the reason I cannot reuse (and this may or may not be the problem) is that I am creating unique markers with a label. The label on the marker contains a reference to the individual marker (consider it like a product ID)

So... in ProductPlot.h

```
@interface ProductPlot : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *productID;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *productID;
```

and ProductPlot.m

```
@implementation ProductPlot
@synthesize productID;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {self.latitude, self.longitude};
    return coord;
}

- (NSString *) productID {
    return productID;
}
```

then I have the annotation view sub classed as ProductPlotView.h

```
@interface ProductPlotView : MKAnnotationView {
ProductPlot *product;
}
```

and in ProductPlotView.m

```
@implementation ProductPlotView

- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if(self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        product = (ProductPlot *)annotation;
        UILabel *plate2 = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        plate2.text = product.productID;
        plate2.frame = CGRectMake(35, 4, 100, 30);
        plate2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //]clearColor];
        [plate2 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"myFont" size: plate2.font.pointSize]];

        [self addSubview:plate2];
    }
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,133,40);

    return self;
}
```

So then in my code, I plot the points using

```
- (void)plotPoint: (int) y latitude: (double) lat longitude: (double) lng productID: (NSString *) pID {

    ProductPlot *newAnnotation = [[ProductPlot alloc] init];
    newAnnotation.latitude = lat;
    newAnnotation.longitude = lng;
    newAnnotation.productID = pID;
    [mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];

    [newAnnotation release];

}
```

I also have the code to handle the annotations.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)lmapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {



    ProductPlotView *eventView = (ProductPlotView *)[lmapView
                                    dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"eventview"];
    if(eventView == nil) {
        eventView = [[[VehicleViewInfo alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                     reuseIdentifier:@"eventview"]
                     autorelease];
    }

    eventView.annotation = annotation;
    return eventView;
}
```

So... the above will take the productID and place it on a label which is the map marker. This seems to work perfectly on the FIRST plot instance, but if I remove the markers (using `[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];`) then call this function again, it draws the points OK, but the product IDs are not correct. It appears to draw them at random.

> NOTE: the code above has had a few
>   parts removed, so there may be typos

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Why don't you post some sample code so we can help you.

From a strategy perspective you should be leveraging a reuse queue just like you would in a tableview. Assuming a common design with different content- Why would you want to force new ones to be created each time? The idea is to avoid allocations and use the efficiency of a reuse queue. Chances are if you started with sample code or followed any of the documentation you will have been on this path.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I will post some code following this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I added `MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;` to the top of my `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)lmapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` code.

Now it seems to be working perfectly. I'd still be keen to see if others think that this is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Reuse queues are the best practice for a reason. You can hack it like so but you are not following the standard design pattern. You'll be fine with a small set of annotations but consider doing things the reuse way.

Comment: Yes I agree totally... I want to reuse, believe me! There will only ever be around 10 markers on the screen at once, but even then I'd rather go for speed. I just need to find a way to delete the label on the marker - or just reset the text within. I'm probably missing something... thanks.

Comment: basically each marker needs to be unique... so if it's reused - I need to then just override the label. I'll have a think and repost the solution (if indeed I find one!)

Comment: You can just override `setAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` in your `MKAnnotationView` subclass (I believe you called it `VehicleViewInfo`). When it gets called, you need to update the label. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem checking subviews on annotation view.
if it hasn't subviews i create a new label and add it as subview, if it has subviews i take the first and edit the label.text property.
In this way subviews are always zero or only one.